# Incorrect layout alignment in list Item of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, listitem

I'm having a problem with setting the layout in RecyclerView.

here is an layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dummy_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
            list.add("item " + i);
        }

        DummyRVAdapter adapter = new DummyRVAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

**Code for Adapter :**

```
public class DummyRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DummyRVAdapter.Holder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mList;

    public DummyRVAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public DummyRVAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_dummy_layout, null);
        //View view =LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_dummy_layout, null);
        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DummyRVAdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of my output.

[image]

In my layout XML file, I declare the size for textView as 50% and Button as 30%
,but still, my recyclerView not showing in a correct manner it is not showing in a correct manner.

**This layout works fine in Listview.**

I don't know where is the problem in my code. I set the **Layout manager and adapter** to my RecyclerView in the correct manner.

**Edit:**
Please see the **ScreenShot** it shows that TextView is not allocating 50% of the screen, that's the problem.

It I create complex Layout for Recyclerview its alignment is not in mentioned format.

**but that works in Listview**

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the weight sum and the then specify weight on button and textview

Comment: Just remove `android:weightSum="1"`

Comment: @GVillani82 I tried that too but still it remains the same problem and the size of the textview is even smaller than this. please see the Screenshot there Textview is not allocating 50% screen size of the device.

Comment: Have you checked the width parameter in the `recycler_view`? It should be `match_parent`

Comment: @GVillani82  yes both the width and height are match_parent. I've updated my question please see the edit

Comment: your recycleview must also have match_parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_dummy_layout, null);
```

use:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).(R.layout.item_dummy_layout, parent, false);
```

Comment: @GVillani82 thanks man it works for me as well but can u please explain whats the difference?

Answer (score 0):

As `android:weightSum="1"`  but sum of all `android:layout_weight` was not equal to 1 so this was not showing properly

you have declare the size for `textView` as 50% and `Button` as 30% but rest remaining is 20% due to this reason it is not showing in proper way. so can do as either increase `textview` to 70% and `Button` to 30% so `android:weightSum` and `android:layout_weight` sum will be equal.

Change your layout to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dummy_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: Why adding another view? Isn't simpler to change the `weightSum` to 0.8 or remove it?

Comment: Please see the screenshot. it shows that TextView is not allocating 50% of the area in a device.

Comment: you want that textview and button should acquire full space in layout in proper way ? right ?

Comment: yes i tried. by changing the  the layout_weight=0.7 in textview. but it's not occupying enough space as i declared

Comment: can you share more details of recyclerView as it is working in my machine.

Comment: you should include proper code to your question.@Madhan

Answer (score 0):

Its not just weight that is having problem its the view textview may be occupying its size but it's text are samller than button size
   one important thing Even after weight or without it use minsize and max size in button to fit it according to need like in your layout do this:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dummy_text_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="Button"
     android:max_height="30dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
```